# creating multiple resources at the same time in terraform

Tags: azure, terraform

I'm writing my first terraform script, I need to create multiple service principal applications. I can used the following script to create each one:

```
resource "azuread_application" "main" {
  name = var.name

  available_to_other_tenants = false

  identifier_uris = [format("http://%s", var.name)]
}

resource "azuread_service_principal" "auth" {
  application_id = "${azuread_application.auth.application_id}"
}

resource "random_string" "password" {
  length = 16
  special = true
  override_special = "/@\" "
}

resource "azuread_service_principal_password" "auth" {
  service_principal_id = "${azuread_service_principal.auth.id}"
  value                = "${random_string.password.result}"
  end_date_relative    = "240h"
}

output "client_secret" {
  value = "${random_string.password.result}"
  description = "Client Secret"
}

provider "azurerm" {
  version = "=1.24.0"
}

data "azurerm_subscription" "primary" {}

data "azurerm_client_config" "current" {}

resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "auth" {
  scope                = "${data.azurerm_subscription.primary.id}"
  role_definition_name = "Reader"
  principal_id         = "${azuread_service_principal.auth.id}"
}
```

let same I want to create 6 of them, when is the best way to reuse this code for all 6 SP?

I know something like this can be done:

```
resource "azuread_application" "auth" {
  name = "${var.sp_names[count.index]}"

  available_to_other_tenants = false

  identifier_uris = [format("http://%s", ${var.sp_names[count.index]})]
  count                = "${length(var.sp_names)}
}
```

but if I do this I do I pass the ide to `azuread_service_principal` block?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To create multiple service principals at the same time via Terraform, you need to use the `count` property in the resource.

Here is the example code:

```
resource "azuread_application" "example" {
    count                      = 2
    name                       = "example-${count.index}"

  available_to_other_tenants = false
  oauth2_allow_implicit_flow = true
}

resource "azuread_service_principal" "example" {
    count                         = 2
    application_id                = "${azuread_application.example[count.index].application_id}"
    app_role_assignment_required  = false
}
```

I saw you also want to set the passwords and role assignments for the service principals, then you also need to use the `count` property in their resources like above.